# getting ' ajv is not a constructor mini-css-extract-plugin ' error whenever installing package using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ajv, mini-css-extract-plugin

whenever I'm trying to install a package from npm I'm getting the following error :
`ajv is not a constructor , mini-css-extract-plugin`
My project is now stopped due to this error I can't download any new package.
This only works if I deleted node_modules and reinstalled it but the same happens again if I download a new package!
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev ajv

updating Ajv should fix it.